# Mean squared error and Euclidean norm in machine learning

Tags: normed-spaces, regression, machine-learning, mean-square-error

I was reading about linear regression and mean squared error in machine learning, and I came across this explanation:

> Suppose that we have a design matrix of $m$ example inputs that we will not use for training, only for evaluating how well the model performs. We also have a vector of regression targets providing the correct value of $y$ for each of these examples. Because this dataset will only be used for evaluation, we call it the test set. We refer to the design matrix of inputs as $\mathbf{X}^{\text{(test)}}$ and the vector of regression targets as $\mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}}$.
>
> One way of measuring the performance of the model is to compute the **mean squared error** of the model on the test set. If $\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}}$ gives the predictions of the model on the test set, then the mean squared error is given by
>
> $$\text{MSE}_{\text{test}} = \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{i} (\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}})_i^2.$$
>
> Intuitively, one can see that this error measure decreases to $0$ when $\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} = \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}}$. We can also see that
>
> $$\text{MSE}_{\text{test}} = \dfrac{1}{m} \vert\vert \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}} \vert\vert_2^2,$$
>
> so the error increases whenever the Euclidean distance between the predictions and the targets increases.

I have two (related) areas of confusion here.

1. What is the $i$ iterating over in the sum?
2. For the latter equation, we have the [$2$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) (the Euclidean norm). But, unless I'm misunderstanding the notation here, we don't necessarily have that $\text{MSE}_{\text{test}} = \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{i} (\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}})_i^2 = \dfrac{1}{m} \vert\vert \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}} \vert\vert_2^2$ for $i = 2$, right? Again, I think I might be confused about the notation here (specifically, for the first equation), so that might be where my confusion comes from. Can someone please clarify this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}}$, and $\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}}$ are vectors of length $m$, and thus so is their difference. $i$ runs from $1$ to $m$ and is iterating over the entries of the vector $\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}}$.

The definition of the Euclidean norm for the vector  $\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}}$ is $\sqrt{\sum_{i} (\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}})_i^2}$, and thus $\text{MSE}_{\text{test}} = \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{i} (\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}})_i^2 = \dfrac{1}{m} \vert\vert \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{\text{(test)}} - \mathbf{y}^{\text{(test)}} \vert\vert_2^2$ actually does hold.